# setTimeout is called immediately in iOS while enabling modal view so modal is not appearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using Modal Wrapper to show modal popup in my code.  We have visible props to enable and disable the modal view according to the boolean value set to it.  I enable the modal view and disable it with setTimeout.  setTimeout is called immediately. I attach my code

```
this.setState({offline: true})
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({offline:false}); 
}, 3000)  
                              

<ModalWrapper containerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-end' }} overlayStyle={{backgroundColor:'transparent'}} visible={this.state.offline} style = {[styles.snackBarView, {bottom:(height === 812) ? 90 : 56}]}>
  <View>
    <Image  style={styles.snackBbarIconOffline} source={require('../Resources/icons/offline.png')} />
  </View>
  <Text style={styles.privacyPolicyText}>{'You are offline'}</Text>
</ModalWrapper>
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? Try adding some console.log inside to check if it is actually getting called immediately or after 3 seconds as it looks good to me..

Comment: I tried it., its getting called immediately that too it happens ly in iOS, in Android it works fine

Comment: Where are you calling setState? in any lifecycle? better show us either entire component or useful parts of it. You need to remove setTimeout in `componentWillUnMount`

Comment: It is called in componentWillReceiveProps

Answer (score 0):

Try this to assess the issue

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
  console.log('called componentWillReceiveProps')
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('called timeout callback')
  }, 3000) 
}
```

There really should be a 3s offset, otherwise there is really something fishy going on.